# Complex reverse query in Django

Tags: django, generics, foreign-keys, reverse

In a nutshell: my models are **B --> A <-- C**, I want to filter **Bs** where at least one **C** exists, satisfying some arbitrary conditions and related to the same **A** as that **B**. Help with some complicating factors (see below) is also appreciated.

Details:

I'm trying to create a generic model to limit user access to rows in other models. Here's a (simplified) example:

```
class CanRead(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Direct(models.Model):
    ...

class Indirect(models.Model):
    direct = models.ForeignKey(Direct)
    ...

class Indirect2(models.Model):
    indirect = models.ForeignKey(Indirect)
    ...
```

It's not feasible to associate a **CanRead** to every row in every model (too costly in space), so only some models are expected to have that association (like **Direct** above). In this case, here's how I'd see if a **Direct** is accessible to a user or not:

```
Direct.objects.filter(Q(canread__user=current_user), rest_of_query)
```

(Unfortunately, this query won't work - in 1.2.5 at least - because of the generic fk; any help with this would be appreciated, but there are workarounds, the real issue is what follows next)

The others' accessibility will be dictated by their relations with other models. So, **Indirect** will be accessible to an user if **direct** is accessible, and **Indirect2** will be if **indirect__direct** is, etc.

My problem is, how can I do this query? I'm tempted to write something like:

```
Indirect.objects.filter(Q(canread__content_object=F('direct'), canread__user=current_user), rest_of_query)

Indirect2.objects.filter(Q(canread__content_object=F('indirect__direct'), canread__user=current_user), rest_of_query)
```

but that doesn't work (Django expects a relation between **CanRead** and **Indirect** - which doesn't exist - for the reverse query to work). If I were writing it directy in SQL, I would do something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM indirect i
    JOIN direct d ON i.direct = d.id
    JOIN canread c ON c.object_id = d.id
  WHERE
    c.content_type = <<content type for Direct>> AND
    c.user = <<current user>> AND
    <<rest_of_query>>
```

but I can't translate that query to Django. Is it possible? If not, what would be the least instrusive way of doing it (using as little raw SQL as possible)?

Thanks for your time!

Note: The workaround mentioned would be not to use generic fk... :( I could discard the **CanRead** model and have many **CanReadDirect**, **CanReadDirect2**, **CanReadDirect3**, etc. It's a minor hassle, but wouldn't hinder my project too much.

Comment: Have you had a look at existing Django authz apps?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Will do. However, it's not only the problem of authorization, this "B-->A<--C" case is something I found quite often, and couldn't figure out the solution by myself. I still miss a solution for the generic fk problem, but culebrón's answer was already a big help for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simple case you've given, the solution is simple:

```
B.objects.filter(a__c__isnull=False)
```

For the actual query, here's my try:

```
Indirect.objects.filter(direct__id__in=
    zip(*CanRead.objects.filter(
           content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Direct)
        ).values_list('id'))[0])
```

But this way is very slow: you extract IDs from one queryset, then do a query with

```
where id in (1, 2, 3, ... 10000)
```

Which is VERY SLOW. We had a similar issue with joins on generic foreign keys in our project and decided to resort to raw queries in the model manager.

```
class DirectManager(Manager):
    def can_edit(self, user):
        return self.raw(...)
```

I'd also recommend checking out the [per-row permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) framework in Django 1.3.

Comment: Thanks! The simple case solution is exactly what I needed. Although it's not only a matter of checking isnull (as I said, it should satisfy some arbitrary condition), as long as I have access to the C model I'm fine. I didn't know you could do a__c this way, nowhere in the docs I found that. Only knew you could _start_ a reverse query with the model name in lowercase, not that you could do that in the middle of a relashionship span.

Answer (score 1):

access control models are not that simple...
use a well-known access control model such as:
DAC/MAC
or
RBAC
also there is a project called django-rbac.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take a closer look at those. But could you advance me what problem you found in my approach? Is there an obvious security hole I didn't see? Just remember that: 1) what I posted here is a simplified version of my actual code; 2) all the code that will touch the app is **trusted** - end users will only have access to the system through views (and I took measures to ensure all views and management commands will respect those permissions).

Comment: I'll back later to leave an answer to your questions,
for now I should say, when you use a model like RBAC, you have a flexible model for your future developments. there are many Ph.D thesis on these models and many people worked on security holes that may be exist. many of those holes solved only after years of researching on this field.